# Library errors after upgrading gcc versions. Unable to figure out what part of my code depends on libgmp

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I'm upgrading a project from gcc 4.3 to 12.1 (a major jump) on Centos 7 & 6 - both 64 bit. As part of that I'm having trouble with what I suspect is an indirect dependency on a very old version of libgmp.

The submodule I'm compiling does not require any external libraries, however while running make I get the error:

`gcc_12.1.0_path/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Google search does not turn out anything useful, issues that turn up are different than my case, my ld_library_path vars, lib paths are set correctly. libgmp v 3 is not available on my machine, and ideally I do not wish to install it, instead figure out where the dependency is and try upgrade it to use a more recent version of libgmp.

Even more confusing is, libgmp3 is not supported by centos 7 (or gcc 12). I'm not sure what part of compilation is dependent on this library, or how that part was successfully compiling with gcc 4 on centos 6.

The command for compilation is
`g++_path -g -Wno-deprecated -D_DEBUG -fPIC  -m64 -DLIN64BIT -I multiple_include_paths -o object_path -c source_file` no -L inclusions

I wish to know two things:

1. In this case, what information should I provide to seek help?
2. Is there any tool for 2nd level or further (indirect) dependency
   analysis? Would a c++ package manager help with such cases?
3. Is it possible to use libgmp v 3 built on another platform and copied to my lib path to resolve this (I do not have immediate access to such a machine or lib hence cannot check immediately)
4. Are there any suspects based on just the message and command?

Comment: *"-c source_file"* - that tells you this is a single-file compile line. This isn't where you're going to find the link step, where -L and -l matter. That comes later, and *will* provide the step that includes -L and -l specifiers in one form or another. Note it is possible you may have dependent libs that have themselves dependencies that eventually lead to libgmp.so without libgmp.so ever exhibiting anywhere in *your* build  config.

Comment: How did you install GCC 12 on CentOS 7? Afaik it only supports GCC 4.*, and devtools collections up to GCC 11.

Comment: 1. "In this case, what information should I provide to seek help?" - You need to provide [mcve]. 2. "Is there any tool for 2nd level or further (indirect) dependency analysis? Would a c++ package manager help with such cases?" - It depends on what kind of project you build. But it is unlikely that such tool exists. 3. "Is it possible to use libgmp v 3 built on another platform and copied to my lib path to resolve this" - You could build libgmp on **other machine** but with the **same platform** (e.g. with the same distro version). The library built for other platform may to not work.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, rightly pointed out. All other modules have compile and link as one command while this one has a link command later which is why I missed it. It links with  X11, Xext, nsl , dl, stdc++, lm, l, nsl, dl, c, and aprojectLib. Perhaps one of these is dependent on libgmp 3 causing the error

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I built it without any issues following standard gcc build instructions, with gmp 6.2 isl 0.24, mpc 1.2.1, and mpfr 4.1, all of which were built from source. We did have some concerns with centos7 not supporting gcc 12 but decided to give it a go as experiment. Downgrading to gcc 10 is on the table for us.

Comment: @Tsyvarev 2. Alright, thanks. 3. Understood, I had the same thoughts. It is not possible to build this version of libgmp on this platform. 1. This is not a pure code problem isolated from it's environment. It is coupled with the platform and env, even if a minimal code example is provided it won't be reproducible without the linked env, how do you expect me to provide a reproducible env?

Comment: You may want to get use of [software collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/) to exclude the possibility that some GCC dependency is missing or broken. ([this](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-8/) one is the latest in the browser, but i think it has up to gcc 11 already provided. Just replace `devtoolset-8` with `devtoolset-11`). If it doesn't solve the issue, i would iteratively analyse which header adds `libgmp.so` by simply removing them and analysing the compiled and linked binary with `ldd`

Comment: This has nothing to do with any code that gets compiled, @TheDreamsWind -- as described this occurs during `make` itself. There is no "compiled and linked binary" it doesn't even go that far. It's manually-installed gcc itself that's broken. Compiling gcc is a challenge. Most likely the newer version of gcc got built against a new version of libgmp, that got installed alongside with it; however gcc's rpath picks up the old system-installed libgmp. Something went wrong with this custom gcc build.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik a few comments above OP said that he compiled GCC 12, so i suppose it's "installed", but since GCC is not just one binary, but a whole toolset, I suggest to use another approach. Software Collection will just help to ensure that all parts are of the same version. For the part of `ldd`, i meant to analise the binary with the working configuration (as stated by OP, it works for CentOS 6/gcc4). But it shouldn't be needed if the problem with GCC, as Software Collection should address it properly